# Can I change my ICS phone camera trigger?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, sony-xperia-arc

I am using Sony Xperia LT18I. It's ICS 4.0.4 and I was wondering about changing the trigger of my phone's camera with the headset key press. If I connect my headset it should find and change it's default option and should take a photo when I press the key of my headset. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Welcome at Stack Oveflow. Everybody was once new here but you noticed that there are always people around to help out. In case you missed it: [help]

Answer (score 0):

You could probably give [Camera Touch-Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sbg.camera&hl=en) a try.

> - Solution for touch phones that did not have hardware camera button such as Samsung GALAXY S II.
> - Making shots on touch phone without touches.
> - Just use hardware buttons "Volume Up" or **headset**.
> - Use "Volume Down" hardware button for exit from application.

Others worth trying:

- [Sensor Camera Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilfredo.bigol.SensorCameraPro):

> (New) Use the headset's previous and forward media button as focus and shutter release.
>   
>   You could also search Google Play for: camera headset

Comment: i tried it but i cant disable the flash!!